# How to use `SELECT COUNT(*)` as a conditional statement in PL/SQL?

Tags: sql, plsql, count

I have a stored procedure that updates records if they exist, or adds a new record if they don't exist.

SQL:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE ADDRECORD(ihost VARCHAR, iip VARCHAR)
AS 
   rc VARCHAR(4000);
   ROWCOUNT NUMBER;
BEGIN
   rc := 'select count(0) from myTable where physical_host =  ihost and primary_ip = iip';
   ROWCOUNT := to_number(rc, '99');

   IF ROWCOUNT = 1 THEN
      UPSERTRECORD(ihost, iip);
   ELSE
      INSERT INTO myTable(PHYSICAL_HOST, PRIMARY_IP)
      VALUES (ihost, iip);
      INSERT INTO IP (IP, IP_IND) VALUES (iip, 'V');
   END IF;    
END ADDRECORD;
```

The `UPSERTRECORD` is another stored procedure that is being called. It works fine. In fact, the error is occurring on the line that contains the `to_number`. The error is :

```
ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character to number conversion error
```

Is there another way to do this? Sorry, I'm not super experienced with SQL, but I need to get this figured out.

Comment: @aleksey.berezan I updated the details with the error attached.

Comment: @HolgerBrandt I have tried it like this: `if rc = 1 then` and still get errors, so I assume that isn't the correct syntax.

Comment: @amlane86 you are setting sql query to a variable but not value returned from query. Your syntax is wrong. you cannot wrap queries in quotes, if you do then they are considered string value but not query for sql engine to execute.

Comment: @rs Makes sense. Your answer below solved my problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do

```
DECLARE rowcount As Number(38)
select count(*) INTO rowcount from myTable 
where physical_host =  ihost and primary_ip = iip
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. The `select count(*) into rowcount` worked perfectly.